# System.IO StreamReader object declaration not working

Tags: c#, winforms, streamreader

I am using System.IO but I still get errors with StreamReader:

> IDE1007: The name "File.OpenText" does not exist in the current
> context.

I have added two images to show the errors.

```
using System.IO;

public partial class frmAnagram : Form
{
    StreamReader StudentNames;
    StudentNames = File.OpenText("");

    int[] theHistogram1 = new int[100];

    public frmAnagram()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I expected stream reader to actually work without issues. I do not know why this file in particular is having a problem. I have used stream reader countless times before with no issues.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [File.OpenText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext?view=net-6.0). Place the code within a method.

Comment: I can't view the images, its best to post errors as text.  But in the code you posted, you aren't giving it any filename.  Are you giving it a filename in your actual code?

Comment: @ frankM_DN File.OpenText("") It should not give an error. But the execution time gives an error that the file was not found

Comment: @baylum, you have to add a reference to the assembly `System.Runtime.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

To use `File.OpenText` it must be used in a `constructor` or `inside a function`

```
using System.IO;

public partial class frmAnagram : Form
{
    String StudentNames;
    int[] theHistogram1 = new int[100];

    public frmAnagram()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("yourFile.txt"))
        {
            StudentNames= sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus, you should implement IDisposable and Dispose() of the reader when you are done with the form

Comment: @HansKeﬆing  You are right. I just wanted to fix the code error. I edited it now

Comment: You could mention that a SteamReader is not required at all, you can simply have `StudentNames = File.ReadAllText("[Some path]")`